# Elasticsearch: filter on aggregated source

Tags: filter, elasticsearch

I have aggregated some data based on a variable and now i want to filter out the document with best score in each bucket i.e. Out of every bucket, only one document will be filtered which is most relevant and scrap other documents.

Comment: As the "question" is written it is a bit hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Try to clarify in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep only some of the documents based on score, you can use [top-hits aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation).

You should just have to specify a size of 1, as the default sorting is made on the score.

This way, you'll have only the most relevant document in your final aggregation bucket.